# Вывод date с учетом временной зоны

Tags: php

Как сделать вывод функций date() и strtotime() в php с учетом временной зоны. Временные зоны хранятся в списке городов и берутся из базы.

Помню была какая-та функция для этого, но найти не могу. Кроме того код сайта огромный и после выполнения кусочка кода, хотелось бы вернуть временные настройки обратно. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Создайте `DateTime` и вызовите `setTimezone` (которая принимает обьект `DateTimeZone`).

Comment: Или установите timeZone по умолчанию с помощью: `date_default_timezone_set`